# React component with provider and connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component:

```
const CreateUI = () => {
  // This prop will be passed to the `WidgetUI` component.
  const data = state.data;

  // This is the root component of the application.
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <h1>My App</h1>
        <p>This is the data: {data}</p>
        <WidgetUI data={data} />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

// This is the `mapStateToProps` function.
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // This returns the `data` state variable as a prop.
  return {
    data: state.data,
  };
};

// This is the `export` statement.
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CreateUI);
```

I got the following error:

> could not find 'store' in the context of connect(CreateUI).

I want to call a Rest API from this component and pass the response to `WidgetUI`. Do I need to wrap this component and use `Provider` there? I wanted to avoid having a parent component just to specify a `Provider`.

Comment: "I wanted to avoid having a parent component just to specify a `Provider`." - This is how it works in React though, here is no shortcut here. If a component want to access a context it ***must*** be provided from higher in the ReactTree. In other words, no React component can provide a context to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the store should be provided in a higher level otherwise it cannot be found, you don't have to create a parent component you just do this:

```js
const CreateUI = () => {
  // You can use the 'data' state variable from Redux store directly here.
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch data from the API and update the Redux store
    fetchDataFromAPI().then((apiData) => {
      if (apiData && apiData.data) {
        // Dispatch an action to update the Redux store with the API response data
        store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_DATA', payload: apiData.data });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <p>This is the data: {data}</p>
      <WidgetUI data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now you create the store and then wrap your main component providing the created store in the *index.js* file:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from "./reducers"; // Import your root reducer.
//...

const store = createStore(rootReducer); // Create the Redux store

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CreateUI />
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: I have multiple components and each component has its own store. Each component in turn has multiple child components. For that purpose, I will have to create a wrapper right?

Comment: why do you want to create multiple stores?